# x86 - Get the current state of the direction flag (DF)

Tags: c, windows, debugging, assembly, x86

I'm trying to get the value of DF from the EFLAGS register.
I tried to use the `LAHF` instruction, but according to the Intel X86 documentation, the instruction loads only the `SF, ZF, AF, PF, CF` flags. However, I'm trying to find an instruction that will give me the value of the DF register.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pushf` then examine stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
pushf                ;Maybe you'll need pushfd
pop  eax
bt   eax, 10
```

If the CF is set then the DF was set!

---

If you don't want to clobber any register, you could use next method (inspired by @fuz):

```
pushf
test byte [esp+1],4
lea  esp, [esp+4]      ;The LEA instruction doesn't change any flags
```

This time if the ZF is set, it means the DF was cleared!

Comment: Slightly better might be `pushf; test byte [esp+1],4`.

Comment: @fuz It would also need popping (without changing the flags of course)! Was your aim to not clobber a register?

Comment: @SepRoland Yes. So the total operation is just `pushf ; test byte [esp+1],4 ; add esp, 4`. Or you pop the next time you need to adjust the stack.

Comment: @fuz Then perhaps a solution that is a bit more forgiving on code placement: `pushf` ; `test byte [esp+1],4` ; `lea esp, [esp+4]` Test result still available.

Answer (score 5):

this also can be done using intrinsic function [__readeflags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983406.aspx) - so not need inline assembly(which work only for x86) - next simply code will be work on both x86 and x64 platform:

```
if (__readeflags() & (1 << 10))
{
    // D flags is set
}
```

however on windows this flag almost always cleared

Comment: Thank you. In my case this flag was set using STD on Windows's DLL

Comment: @Aviv - windows assume that this flag always clear. many functions used structure initializations with `rep stosX` or memory copy with `rem movsX` and they not check this flag but assume that it 0. if set it to 1 - process with possibility near 100% crashed. only some functions (like `memove` ) on short time set this flag and than clear it

Comment: @RbMm I know MSDN lists it as a requirement for the MSVC C standard library when calling its functions but is it spelled out as a requirement anywhere for the WinAPI ABI?

Comment: @Anders - this is standard agreement for windows. all windows function  written based on assumption that this flag is clear. set it to 1 - your  with possibility near 100% crash own process

Comment: @RbMm, you are right, the function was memmove on msvcrt.dll

Comment: @Aviv wait a second, you mean it didn't restore the DF to 0? That shouldn't happen?

Comment: @Ped7g of course memmove restore DF to 0 if set it to 1 for reverse copy

Comment: @Ped7g, as RbMm said, it does set the flag and restore it right after the instruction

Comment: @Aviv yeah, but that's like "obvious", there're only so many ways how to reasonably implement memmove, the msvcrt is using pretty much the same code as we did back in early days... from your comment it almost did sound like it didn't restore it, **that** would surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `es:edi` points to valid memory area and you don't mind to modify it (and `eax`), and you want +1/-1 result instead of 0/1:

```
mov eax,edi
scasb
sub edi,eax   ; edi = +1/-1 for DF=0/1
```

Hm, there's so many if/and/when constraints to this, that it's probably not useful (only advantage: doesn't need/modify stack). But I did want to try how cumbersome it would be to read the result of one of string instruction, as I got that idea while reading the `pushf` answer.

---

edit: stack memory variant, which will be usually valid for read access (especially if the `pushf` variant in other answer works) (NASM syntax).

```
mov esi,esp
ss lodsb      ; size of LODS can change result to +-2 or +-4 (+-8 in 64b)
sub esi,esp   ; esi = +1/-1 for DF = 0/1, does clobber AL
; sets al     ; to get AL = 0/1 for DF = 0/1
```

Comment: I like this, since it avoids the horrible breakage that is `pushf` (which tends to come in pairs with `popf`, which breaks virtualization).

Comment: @EOF: it can also produce +-2, +-4 or +-8 results by changing size of `scas`. :D I don't think it's useful, because if you know the `es:edi` points to readable memory, then you probably know enough about your runtime environment to also know current DF value, I can't see using this in my own code. Also overall, except debugging output, why would one care what is in DF? You just set it up as you need it or as ABI prescribes it.

Comment: You tend to have a stack, so getting a pointer to readable (and writable) memory is usually trivial.

Comment: @EOF ty, modified to "just work", clobbers `esi, al`, needs valid stack (the `pushf` variant needs one too, even not-full, this one works over full stack as well). And if somebody needs 0/1 result as DF itself, he can do `sets al` after `sub`.